# How does this program work. Im rookie in programming so please explain it in simplified way

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

please explain to me how program output

```
a noise
annoy
an oyester
```

```
while ( x < 4 ) {
    System.out.print("a");
    if ( x < 1 ) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("n");
    if (x> 1 ) {
        System.out.print(" oyster");
        x = x + 2;
    }
    if ( x == 1 ) {
        System.out.print("noys");
    }
    if ( x < 1 ) {
        System.out.print("oise");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    x = x + 1;
```

Comment: What output do you need?

Comment: There is a missing bracket in your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the first line is a while-loop it keeps evaluating the statements in between the {} brackets if the condition x<4 is fulfilled.

```
   while ( x < 4 ) {
```

- Let's assume x = 0
- x<4 is a true statement so we enter the brackets:
- `System.out.print("a");` will print 'a'
- the next line `if ( x < 1 ) {`  is an if statement, it will evaluate the code in the brackets **once** if the condition (x < 1) is fulfilled. Because x is 0 at this point the condition is true.
- `System.out.print(" "); this will print a space
- `System.out.print("n");` this line in not in the brackets of the if-statement so it will also print.
- `if (x> 1 ) {` x is 0 at this point so the condition is false and the program will skip everything in between these brackets
- `if ( x == 1 ) {` this condition is also false because x is 0 so the program will skip everything in between these brackets
- `if ( x < 1 ) {` this condition is true and `System.out.print("oise")`` prints "oise"
- `System.out.println("");` starts a new line
- `x = x + 1;` the x variable is incremented by one: new x = 0 + 1 = 1

**So the first iteration of the while statement yields:**

> a noise

For the second iteration of the while loop:

x is 1 and we follow the logic sequence again:

- `while ( x < 4 ) {` this is true so we enter the brackets
- `System.out.print("a");` a is printed
- `if ( x < 1 ) {` this statement is false, so next line is skipped
- `System.out.print("n");` n is printed
- `if ( x < 1 ) {` this statement is false, so next line is skipped
- `if (x> 1 ) {` this statement is false, so next two lines are skipped
- `if ( x == 1 ) {` this is true
- `System.out.print("noys");` noys is printed
- the next if-statement is also false
- `System.out.println("");` a new line is started
- `x = x + 1;` and x is incremented

**So the second iteration of the while-statement yields:**

> annoy

I think it is a good exercise now for you to try and figure out what happens in the next iteration of the while-loop.